# clojure macro unquote splicing list of function calls

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to write an ACL module by writing a macro, this macro is to check the result of each function call in the macro, if one return false, then the ACL will fail without run the following function call. If one return true and there are still function calls to check, then check the following until the last one.

```
(defmacro checks
  [head & tail]
  `(let [status# ~head]
     (if (and (true? status#)
              (seq '~tail))
       (checks ~@tail)
       status#)))
```

I will call this macro like this:

```
(checks (module1 args) (module2 args))`
```

but this will fail for `(check ~@tail)` in the macro definition. The problem is that I want to ***Unquote Splicing*** the list but without calling each function in the list.

Comment: Just a tip, don't use backticks for formatting large pieces of code. Indent it by four spaces by highlighting it and pressing ctrl+k.

Comment: Won't `and` macro do the same?

Comment: Thanks you guys for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way to solve this issue:

```
(defmacro checks
  [head & tail]
  (let [sym (gensym)]
    `(let [~sym ~head]
       (if ~sym
         ~(if tail
            `(checks ~@tail)
            sym)
         ~sym))))
```

use syntax unquote again on outer the `(checks ~@tail)` form.

Comment: Cleaner than [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46378055/1562315). It's just [`and`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L834) by another name, without the zero arity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are generating the code for the recursive call to the macro even though there is no argument.

```
(macroexpand-1 '(checks 1))
=>
(clojure.core/let
 [status__1973__auto__ 1]
 (if
  (clojure.core/and (clojure.core/true? status__1973__auto__) (clojure.core/seq (quote nil)))
  (user/checks)
  status__1973__auto__))
```

The inner macro call fails because it needs at least one argument. No matter how many arguments you supply to the macro, its expansion eventually generates the failing call.

You need to establish whether there is anything in `tail` before generating the recursive call to `checks`:

```
(defmacro checks
  [head & tail]
  (if-not tail
    head
    `(let [status# ~head]
       (if (true? status#)
         (checks ~@tail)
         status#))))
```

Now

```
(macroexpand-1 '(checks 1))
=> 1

(checks 1)
=> 1
```

And

```
(macroexpand-1 '(checks 1 2 3))
=>
(clojure.core/let
 [status__2010__auto__ 1]
 (if (clojure.core/true? status__2010__auto__) (user/checks 2 3) status__2010__auto__))
```

Furthermore

```
(checks 1 2 3)
=> 1
(checks true true 3)
=> 3
```

As @PiotrekBzdyl's comment suggests, this is just an `and` macro that treats anything other than `true` as false.

Comment: Thanks.  This macro will generate the incorrect recursive call.